# Swiping across a complex DOM

Tags: javascript, animation, translate3d

I'm building a webapp where people can swipe through sections. These sections are filled with mostly listviews. My current setup is as follows:

- on touchmove: set a new translate3d value
- on touchend: calculate the translate3d value where the container of the sections should snap to and animate there through rAF.

However, when I swipe, i'm getting various points where "composite layers" takes dozens of ms (somewhere around 40-70). I have avoided complex calculations such as box-shadow, so I'm wondering how I could improve this? The rest of the JS is OK in processing; the event takes up about 3ms, recalculate style takes another 3ms, but then's the big said chunk of "composite layers".

Comment: How are you setting the `translate3d` value in your `touchmove` handler? Same on `touchend`? Create a fiddle if possible please, hard to imagine what the problem could be.

Comment: I've created a swipeObserver module which passes the DOMnode in an "onmove" callback. I'm setting style.transform, style.webkitTransform etc in this callback.

Comment: tried adding a pseudo `translateZ` to your `transform`? I am guessing you are well aware of how chrome can help you debug and improve [rendering performance](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/). Specially the part about [compositing](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/stick-to-compositor-only-properties-and-manage-layer-count).

Comment: Adding translateZ is the same as using translate3d, isn't it...?

Comment: duh! my bad. It is. Hard to debug without code to be honest? jsFiddle possible?